# How to extract all the user's username who are online from firebase database.

Tags: android, firebase

I want to extract all the user's username (highlighted blue) who are online (highlighted red) from a firebase database to a list view.

[image]

Comment: `Query queryRef = myFirebaseRef.Child(
"drivers").orderByChild("online").equalTo("true");`

Comment: What do I do to this? Can you give a full example please? I'm new to firebase.

Comment: I am not an android developer... but this is how you need to add query than add obsever to fetch values .....

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data

Comment: Hey A. Omar!, here, what should I use? Child listeners or value

Comment: @KarunShrestha you can use value

Comment: This question will help me a lot in the future

Comment: Hope there'll be an answer. All the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to the question, thanks to A. Omar and Frank van Puffelen for the help:

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReferenceFromUrl("https://<your-app>.firebaseio.com/drivers/");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot driverSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                if(driverSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString()=="true"){
                Log.d(TAG, driverSnapshot.getKey() + " - " + driverSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString());
                }
            }
        }

        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

this will print only the online users like:

2332424 - true

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're using a deprecated method ^^ https://www.firebase.com/docs/ Migration guide: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android xD

Comment: oh, sorry didn't know that. Will update the answer. It's still works though.

Comment: @A.Omar Thanks man, your time and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Just tested this, and it works!

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("drivers");
Query query = reference.orderByChild("online").equalTo("true");


query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot.toString());
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
```

Comment: You'll probably want to loop over the drivers in your `onDataChange()`. E.g. `for (DataSnapshot driverSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { Log.d(TAG, driverSnapshot.getKey() + " - " + driverSnapshot.child("available").getValue()); }`

Comment: What's the import for "FirebaseReference"? what library dependency should I include?

Comment: Oups sorry it's **DatabaseReference**. I just edited my answer

Comment: @A.Omar, your code only prints this (DataSnapshot { key = drivers, value = null })

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I think your way is right but it's not working either, it's printing nothing.

Comment: When you created the database with Firebase, did you create it at https://yourproject.firebaseio.com/drivers ?

Comment: No, yourproject.firebaseio.com/uber-1334/drivers

Comment: wait, sorry, I created the database at https://yourproject.firebaseio.com/drivers

Comment: I did some test and the problem comes because of the boolean. I don't know why but if you try to order by an other child it works... I'm still trying to figure out why

Comment: I've figured out the solution, check out my answer. Thanks to both of you guys! :)

Comment: Hey @A.Omar Do I have to use different instance of FirebaseDatabase for different DatabaseReference?